# Why is a value in my Form not being passed to the Google code?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-app-engine, slider

I have a Google SideBar populated from a HTML file. This has a button that when pressed passes a number of values from the Form to the Google Apps Script that then deals with the data before passing it to a Google Sheet.

Everything works fine except for 1 thing:

The slide bar that I have created does not pass the value along with all of the other aspects.

Can anyone explain why?

I have an extensive amount of code so what you will see is only the relevant cut down required amount.

## HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
<br>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td><p>Action Description: </p></td>
      <td colspan="3"> <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="15" cols="22" required> </textarea> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Current Completion Percentage: </p></td>
      <td> 
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="percent" step="10" onchange="outputUpdate(value)" list="perstep">
        <datalist id="perstep">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>20</option>
          <option>30</option>
          <option>40</option>
          <option>50</option>
          <option>60</option>
          <option>70</option>
          <option>80</option>
          <option>90</option>
          <option>1000</option>
        </datalist>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><output for="form1" id="level">0</output>%</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Assigned To: </p></td>
      <td colspan="3"> <input id="assignedto" name="assignedto" type="text" required /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Action Number: </p></td>
      <td colspan="3"> <input id="actionnum" name="actionnum" type="number" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <hr>

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="3" height="40">
        <input id="date" name="date" type="date" required />
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Submit" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="google.script.host.close()" type="button" value="Close" /><br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="clearAll()" type="button" value="Clear All" name="clear" /><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

## Google .gs Code:

```
function getValuesFromForm(form1){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
        sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Action Plan'),
        sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Problem Details'),
        description = form1.description,
        percent = form1.percent,
        assignedto = form1.assignedto,
        actionnum = form1.actionnum,
        date = form1.date,
        oldNum = sheet2.getRange(11, 1).getValue(),
        today1 =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT","dd/MM/yyyy"),
        lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn(),
        lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(),
        datecheck = sheet.getRange(1,lastCol).getValue();

  if(description == "" || assignedto == "" || date == ""){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please ensure you have completed the minimal required fields');
  } else {        
    if(datecheck == Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT","dd/MM/yyyy")) {
      sheet.appendRow([oldNum +1, description, percent + " %", assignedto,date]);
      sheet.getRange(lastRow +1,lastCol).setValue("New Action");
      var head = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lastCol);
      head.setBackground("#b4a7d6");
      head.setFontColor("white");
      head.setFontWeight("bold");
      head.setFontSize(12);
      sheet2.getRange(11, 1).setValue(oldNum + 1);
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(1,lastCol + 1).setValue(today1);
      sheet.appendRow([oldNum +1, description, percent + " %", assignedto,date]);
      sheet.getRange(lastRow +1,lastCol +1).setValue("New Action");
      var head = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,lastCol + 1);
      head.setBackground("#b4a7d6");
      head.setFontColor("white");
      head.setFontWeight("bold");
      head.setFontSize(12);
      sheet2.getRange(11, 1).setValue(oldNum + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

All I get at the moment is "unspecified".

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element that creates the slide bar, `<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="percent" step="10" onchange="outputUpdate(value)" list="perstep">`, lacks a `name` attribute, so it never gives any contribution to the submitted data. So add a `name` attribute with a suitable value.

Comment: I can't believe I missed something so simple! - Thank You!